# Redux Saga - Wait for another action to complete that may or may not have ever run

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

There are plenty of articles on synchronous/waiting on tasks, but I couldn't find one that matches my use case.

I have 3 actions - save, submit and delete, of an entity. I call save when a value of a form changes, which triggers an API call. So this just fires off an event every few seconds during ordinary use. To combat out of sync-ness, I use an action channel and buffer to ensure that this behaves as I want, sort of like a synchronous takeLatest.

```
const saveBuffer = buffers.sliding(1);
function* saveWatcher() {
  const saveChannel = yield actionChannel('SAVE', saveBuffer);

  while (true) {
    const payload = yield take(saveChannel);
    yield call(save, payload);
  }
}
```

For example, let's say save is:

```
save() {
  try {
    yield delay(5000);

    yield put(actions.saveSuccess());
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.saveError());
  }
}
```

Now, when I fire off a delete/submit, I want to make sure we're not in the middle of a save. I thought I could get this to work by checking if the buffer is empty, but this does not work as an empty buffer could still mean we're in the middle of a save.

It's also possible that **save is never called**. For example, we publish without making a change.

I tried something like this:

```
function* waitForPendingSaves() {
  const hasPendingSaves = !saveBuffer.isEmpty();

  if (hasPendingSaves) {
    yield race([
      take(constants.SAVE_SUCCESS),
      take(constants.SAVE_ERROR),
    ]);
  }
}
```

but as mentioned, this deletes mid-save as the buffered item is dequeued and processed. I was thinking of maybe some sort of toggle that goes on when 'SAVE' event is processed, and then off again when 'SAVE_SUCCESS/ERROR' is done, but not sure how to do that nicely.

How can I ensure that `save` is currently not running when I trigger another action?

It may be worth nothing that I do want the task to finish, so cancelling it is out of the equation.

Comment: Do you mean to implement debouncing?

Comment: Also, would be open to consider to fetch the API in the redux action itself, rather than the saga function?

Comment: One way to solve this is to keep an array of promises of all the save API calls, and activate submit button only when all of them are in resolved/rejected state.

Comment: I can probably solve the manual thing I did with debouncing (it's debounced on the effect level but could move this to saga). Though I don't want to show a perpetual loading spinner or disabled buttons while they continue to type on the form. The second I type a letter, itll set "saving" to true, disable submit/delete, and itll stay disabled/saving until I stop typing and the save occurs, right? Not ideal UX, but a temporary workaround at least, but I would like to try and solve this in the ideal way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have debounced on the effect level, why don't you add the API on the effect level? That's the whole point of debouncing?

And yes, it is a tradeoff, better UX with loose consistency vs slightly annoying UX with strong consistency.

Another solution is You don't really have to actually disable the submit button.

After the user clicks on submit button, you can add a loading on the submit button, once all the promises in the save API array are resolved/rejected you can then call submit API and after submit API is resolved, you can disable the loading of submit button. You will have to make sure that user input is also disabled while submit button is disabled. Else if user keeps on writing after clicking on submit button, the save API state and submit button state will have different latest data.